# Rao-Blackwell unbiased estimator geometric distribution

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

I'm looking at review questions and having trouble with this one!
Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be i.i.d. geometric R.V.s with the pmf: $(1-p)^{x-1}p$, for $x=1,2,\ldots$ and $0<p<1$.

I need to use rao-blackwellization to find an unbiased estimator for $p(1-p)$. The examples of Rao-Blackwellization I have all involve bernoulli variables, and I'm running into difficulty when I try to generalize this. 
Here is what I have come up with so far:

An unbiased statistic $w$ for $p-p^2$ can be written as $\frac{1}{X_1}-\frac{1}{X_1 \cdot X_2}$, since $E(X)=\frac{1}{p}$ in a geometric distribution. Further, a quick look at the joint distribution shows $\sum{X_i}$ to be a minimal sufficient statistic.

I run into trouble when I try to set up and compute $E(w\mid t)$. With bernoulli variables, this seemed pretty straight-forward: the expected value can only be 1 or 0. In this case, however, I have no idea how to proceed. I apologize if my question is lacking detail here; the truth is I'm completely stuck. Any hints or advice on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I only just learned about Rao-Blackwellization.

So first, $E[X]=1/p$, but $$E[1/X]=-\frac{p\log p}{1-p},$$ so your $w$ has the wrong expected value.

Notice that $P(X=2)=(1-p)p$, so choose, for example, $w=I[X_1=2]$. (This is much like the example [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rao%E2%80%93Blackwell_theorem).) Then
$$ E[w\mid\sum_i X_i=t] = P(X_1=2\mid\sum_i X_i=t) = \frac{P(X_1=2,\sum_i X_i=t)}{P(\sum_i X_i=t)}. $$

So this is
$$ \frac{P(X_1=2)P(\sum_{2\leq i\leq n}X_i = t-2)}{P(\sum_{1\leq i\leq n}X_i = t)}, $$
where a sum of i.i.d. geometric random variables follows a negative binomial distribution.

Comment: Ah! How embarrassing - i think this makes a great deal more sense to me now. Hopefully it should be smooth sailing from here - I really appreciate the help!

Comment: sorry, I think I might have one question still. For our geometric variables, we label each success as 1 and the failure 0. So wouldn't $X_1 = 1$ in this case? It's difficult to rationalize it currently...
Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're saying. From the way you defined the pdf, $I[X_1=2]$ is an unbiased estimator of $p(1-p)$, whereas $I[X_1=1]$ would be an unbiased estimator of $p$.

Comment: Whoops, you're correct! Misread my own pdf (how embarrassing). Thanks again for the help :)