# Mean of a sampling distribution.

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose $\hat{p}=1/\overline{X}$ is an estimator of the parameter $p$ of a population variable $X\sim\text{Geo}(p)$.  Suppose $p=0.36$ and $n=25$.  What is the mean of the sampling distribution?

This is a homework question I am rehashing to prepare for an exam.  The solution given by the instructor is that $E[\hat{p}]=p=0.36$.  I don't understand this result.  I would say that $E[\hat{p}]=E[1/\overline{X}]\geq1/E[\overline{X}]=1/\mu=1/(1/p)=p.$  The inequality is Jensen's Inequality, and it should in fact be a strict inequality since the function $f(x)=1/x$ is not linear and $\overline{X}$ is not constant.  That is, $E[\hat{P}]>p$.  As far as finding $E[\hat{p}]$ exactly, I don't know what to do.

Can anybody help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your professor is incorrect. See this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384929/rao-blackwell-unbiased-estimator-geometric-distribution). $\hat P$ is only asymptotically unbiased. However, it will converge rather quickly, so it may be practically unbiased, just like the sample standard deviation, which is very biased for small samples, but quickly becomes essentially unbiased for typical sample sizes.

However, you can get a UMVUE for $\frac{(1-p)}{p}$ see [here.](http://web.ipac.caltech.edu/staff/fmasci/home/statistics_refs/UsefulDistributions.pdf)

Also, to empirically validate this, just get an excel spreadsheet and populate a column with 10 geometric RVs, ten use them to calculate yoru estimator and compare it to $p$, you will see that you are consistently high.

Comment: Thank you.  I spoke to the professor and he noted that I was correct but that the instructions were to proceed as if we were using the rule of large n for an MLE estimator.  I missed that.

Comment: @nonremovable I see, so you are invoking SLLN. Then the result makes sense (asymptotically)